# Select-String to only show the line that matches not entire object

Tags: powershell, tostring

How can I get this to only show the single line, not the entire object, like grep in bash.
`Out-String -Stream` should convert it to a string, I have tons of jsons structures and currently I filter in python onelines

```
Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Name | Where-Object -Property Name -Match "Winrm" |\
ConvertTo-Json | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Name'

{
    "Name":  "WinRM"
}
```

Python oneliner is a bit inconvenient :-) :

```
Get-Service | ConvertTo-Json | \
python.exe -c "import sys,re;[sys.stdout.write(l) for l in sys.stdin if re.search(r'WinRM', l)]"                                
        "ServiceName":  "WinRM",
        "Name":  "WinRM",
```

Comment: `Get-Service -Name "WinRM"` ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this!

(Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Name | Where-Object -Property Name -Match "Winrm").Name

Comment: If you have json input, then you can use ConvertFrom-Json and get the value. Similar to jq

Comment: It is filtering on json that is the question, Get-Service is just the smallest example I found that can generate a json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-String` works on a string array and returns the element that matches the pattern.  Your JSON string is still a single string, but if you split it on newlines, you can then use the `Select-String` command to get just the line that includes `Name` and omit curly braces.  The following example helps illustrate this.

```
$TestJSON = @'
{
    "Name":  "WinRM"
}
'@

$TestJSON | Select-String -Pattern 'Name'
# {
#     "Name":  "WinRM"
# }


($TestJSON.Split([Environment]::NewLine) | Select-String -Pattern 'Name' | Out-String).Trim() # Note that 'Trim' removes whitespace around your desired value
# "Name":  "WinRM"
```

So to put it all together, you can get the `Name` property and it's value with JSON formatting but without the surrounding curly braces using the following one-liner.

```
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "WinRM" } | Select-Object -Property Name | ConvertTo-Json | ForEach-Object { $_.Split([Environment]::NewLine) } | Select-String -Pattern "Name" | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
# "Name":  "WinRM"
```

And to walk through this...

- We get all the services
- We filter out the WinRM service
- We select the `Name` property
- We convert that to JSON
- We split the JSON output on each newline to generate a string array
- We return the element of the string array that contains `Name`
- We convert whatever is coming down the pipe into a string
- We use the `Trim` function to remove whitespace around the string

Comment: Splitting the json and use Trim was the key. A bit harder than `grep WinRM`

Comment: @MortenB Glad it helped! Please feel free to mark this as the solution when you get the chance :)